# How to change prompt responses to input boxes in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, command-prompt, prompt

```
                         Long Detailed Question
```

I put a part of my code below. It is a small javascript game I am working on. When the game wants to know something, or take an text input from the user, I use the prompt command, which as you probably know brings up an alert box that displays some text and lets the user submit a text response. I want to know how I can change it, so instead of an alert box that pops up there is just a input box on the screen that takes their text response. I assume the code needed would either be JQuery(which I do not have much experience in) or JavaScript.

```
                          Short Summarized Question
```

> > > **So in summary I want to know how I can make an input box that takes text inputs similar to how a prompt alert does**<<<

```
                                    Code
var finishAnt = prompt(
                 "you can either risk your life and finish him, or try to run away. Do you finish him?").toLowerCase()
             if (finishAnt == "yes") {
                 console.log("congratulations you have killed the aint eater!")
             } else if (finishAnt == "no") {
                 console.log(
                     "You run away and barley make it, you are badly hurt");
             } else {
                 console.log("sorry thats not an option")
             }
         } else if (meetAnt == "no") {
             console.log(
                 "You run past the ant eater and get to saftey. You are very lucky")
         } else {
             console.log("Sorry that is not an option.")
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use Jquery for this, or you can use `document.getElementsByTagName('input').value`, assign it to a variable, and act accordingly. Like if the user selects yes to the first, the value of the input box will be set to the boolean: `true` or a string: `yes`. Then take those values and display a message based on the results.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to translate this code directly. You will need to make some significant changes to your code to support it.

The `alert()`, `prompt()` and `confirm()` Javascript functions are unique in that they block execution of scripts until the dialog is dismissed. Essentially all other methods in Javascript, including DOM methods that allow you to manipulate and respond to events in a HTML page, are all *non-blocking* — that is, they must execute immediately, and cannot wait for an event to occur.

To rework this code to run within a page, you will need to reformulate it as a [*state machine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). This will entail keeping track of what state your game is in at any given point and responding appropriately to events based on that state. For instance, you might write a part of your game as:

```js
var state;

function print(msg) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = msg;
}

function takeInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (state == "which-door") {
    if (input == "left") {
      print("You open the left door and fall into a bottomless pit. What now?");
      state = "bottomless-pit";
    } else if(input == "right") {
      print("You open the right door and find yourself lost outdoors...");
      state = "outdoors";
    } else {
      print("That isn't a door. Which door do you open?");
      state = "which-door";
    }
  } else if (state == "bottomless-pit") {
    print("You're still falling down a bottomless pit...");
    state = "bottomless-pit";
  } else if (state == "outdoors") {
    print("Now you're back at those two doors again. Left or right?");
    state = "which-door";
  }
  // ... etc ...
});

// Make the "go" element call the takeInput() method when clicked
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", takeInput);

// Start out in the "which-door" state and display an introduction:
state = "which-door";
print("Do you open the left door or the right door?");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<div>
  <input id="input" size="40">
  <button id="go">Go</button>
</div>
```

See the basic framework of this code? At each step, you're taking the current state and input into account, and using those to decide how to respond (by calling `print()`, typically), and what state to enter next.

(Note that this structure means that it's much easier to introduce logical loops into your game, as it's no longer necessary to represent them as control structures. For instance, the "bottomless-pit" state in this example loops back to itself, and the "outdoors" state loops back to the "which-door" state.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify JS presets, but you can make mockups of them in Visual Basic (TEXT/VBSCRIPT)

Comment: that shouldn't be an answer, but a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try using CSS to make a fake popup. That'll make it look real. Or embed a PNG. But be warned. Embedding a PNG could result in the user dragging it and finding out it's fake. Try using Animate.CSS to let it pop up in the Windows fashion.